# Building android apk in ionic throws error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

When i run `ionic build android --prod --release` its gives me below output

```
The build command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

  ionic cordova build --help
```

I don't know why its give me this error
when i run

> ionic info

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

    Node       : v6.10.3
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

Please help me with above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact I faced this error with ionic 3.3 before update all thing.
so you need to reinstall the last version of cordova and ionic( now it is 3.3.2)
or Simply, just you need to use

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```